# Set attributes and return different ones

Tags: python

I need to make a get request to a website.  I have a private method __get_req which does it.
But I have to set attributes (url, headers, params) and to get only the response from get request.

I have tried to make tuples and to set listed attributes as a tuple but it doesn't make sense

```
def __get_req(self, url, headers, params, session):
    self.__r = session.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

def getter_req(self):
    return self.__r

def setter_g_req(self, url, headers, params, session):
    self._url = url
    self._headers = headers
    self._params = params
    self._session = session
```

Comment: Why don't you use the values you set in ```setter_g_req``` in the ```__get_req```

Comment: why do you waste time to create private method and setter ?